# How do I Limit asp:Repeater in asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I'm a beginner with ASP.net and now, I want to limit the item in my asp:repeater (It's a RSS feed)

This is my code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rssRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="border: solid 1px black; width: 500px; font-family: Arial">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("link")%>' Text='<%#Eval("title")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: #C2D69B">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("description")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

EDIT :

Code behind

```
try
            {

                WebResponse rep = rssReq.GetResponse();

                XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream());

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xtr);

                rssRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
                rssRepeater.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

have you got a property to limit the display of items ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you show us the code where you bind the data to the repeater?

Comment: In code-behind, use Linq to limit the number of items before assigning your list to the repeater: rssRepeater.DataSource = YourRssItems.Take(numberofrows);

Comment: I edited my first post for the code-behind

Comment: Try a DataList control instead of a repeater. It has support for paging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no properties in the repeater that controls the number of rows but you can control it from the DataSource or the SQL query that binds this repeater